# Problema con $_POST,$_GET... con doble dolar

Tags: php

Tengo este código para validar seguridad:

```
$tipos = array('$_POST','$_GET','$_COOKIE','$_SESSION','$_FILES');
foreach($tipos as $tipo){
    if ( isset($$tipo) && !empty($$tipo) ) {
        foreach ($$tipo as $key => $item) {
            $tipo[$key] = $this->security->xss_clean($item);
        }
    }
}
```

Me da error de `undefined` variable, se que podria validarlo uno por uno, pero hay solución de esta forma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el segundo foreach debes usar `$$tipo[$key]` en vez de `$tipo[$key]` y tu array tipos no deben tener el `$`. Debería quedar así:

```php
$tipos = array('_POST','_GET','_COOKIE','_SESSION','_FILES');
foreach($tipos as $tipo){
    if ( isset($$tipo) && !empty($$tipo) ) {
        foreach ($$tipo as $key => $item) {
            $$tipo[$key] = $this->security->xss_clean($item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Me sale: <p>Message:  Undefined variable: _POST</p>